# Converting a String into a Valid DateTime Format

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have two Timestamps that are saved to and read from two XML files.
Currently I am reading the timestamps from the xml files in a `WCF Service` method, so they are coming in as `Strings` , but I need them to be converted into `DateTime` so they can be compared.

The obvious `Convert.ToDateTime(TimeStampString)` renders this error at Runtime -

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

As does

```
DateTime.ParseExact(TimeStampString, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:MM:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Both Timestamps are in the correct format for `DateTime` (`mm/dd/yyyy hh:MM:ss`).

I've even tried splitting the timstamp strings into `String[]` and assembling my own `DateTime` object by hand, and I still received the error.

**Is this a format issue? 
How can I make my String a valid DateTime?**

Comment: what is the string that it's breaking on?

Comment: The string comes in from the XML as `"05/11/1995 14:34:17"` .

Comment: Why are you specifying only a 2 digit year in your ParseExact call then? What happens if you use the correct mask?

Comment: I specify a 4 digit year , I've written it wrong in my question. Woops!

Comment: Please see my post. It's usually safer to use TryParseExact than ParseExact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by removing any attempts to alter the format from US, so Strings came in with US format - then used an `IFormatProvider` to alter the format at conversion time.

```
IFormatProvider localFormat = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", true);
DateTime ContentLastUpdatedTime = DateTime.Parse(ContentLastUpdatedStamp, localFormat , System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
DateTime ContentLastGrabbedTime = DateTime.Parse(LastGrabbedTimeStamp, localFormat , System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a format issue

```
mm/dd/yy hh:MM:ss
```

should be

```
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

*(basically, swap the upper case `MM` in the date & the lowercase `mm` in the time)*

Comment: My bad, that is actually how it is in my code - ive got it wrong in the question! Sorry!

Comment: lower case `mm` is for minutes. It should be swapped in the format you provided.

Comment: Also the hour part is for 24 hours format, it should be upper case `HH` not lower case `hh`

Comment: @piggy If there's a mistake in the question, you should [edit] your question and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
DateTime.ParseExact(TimeStampString, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

instead of

```
DateTime.ParseExact(TimeStampString, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:MM:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

**The issue is lower case `mm` which is used for minutes,** You need `MM` upper case `MM`, plus your date is in 24 hours format, and you need upper case `HH` for hour part , so your format should be:

```
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

*(considering you have `yyyy` in your original code based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702799/converting-a-string-into-a-valid-datetime-format/29702919#comment47541464_29702864))*

See: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the handy tip! Although it's still not working I'm afraid.

Comment: @piggy:- Have you checked that the order of month and date is MM/dd and not dd/MM ?

Comment: @piggy, this format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` for current date should work fine. Make sure you don't have `dd/MM` and also that you have a double digit day/month in string values.

Comment: @piggy try `M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss` I am guessing that you may have single digit day/month part in your string.

Answer (score -2):

Here you go

```
var dtedatetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz");


DateTimeOffset dto;
bool bIsParsed = DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(dtedatetime , "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzz",
                                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                    DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dto);

    var result = dto.DateTime;
```